# It’s possible to have many different app services pointing to the same subdomain?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I saw that is possible creating only one app service with many virtual directories, but I’m not sure if this is a good practice.

I want the following:

1. foo.mywebsite.com/web1 -> foo-web1.azurewebsites.net
2. foo.mywebsite.com/web2 -> foo-web2.azurewebsites.net

Any idea?

Comment: You're just asking if this is good practice?

Comment: @jhpratt no, I want to know if there is any way to do what I said. But it’s ok to say also if is a good practice the virtual directories way with same app service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Azure Application Gateway to Azure web app to route requests by path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136636/configuring-azure-application-gateway-to-azure-web-app-to-route-requests-by-path)